# How to reduce redundancy too many elsif clauses? [ruby]

Tags: ruby

```
def roll_die
  rand(1..6)
end

if roll_die == 1
  puts "ruby"
elsif roll_die == 2
  puts "uW"
elsif roll_die == 3
  puts "eBay"
elsif roll_die == 4
  puts "meditate"
elsif roll_die == 5
  puts "musiClean"
else
  puts "medicate"
end
```

How do I decrease the redundancy in my code?

Comment: Your logic is flawed, you're rolling the die multiple times.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code refactoring and review, and should be on [codereview.se] instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using [`Array#sample`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-sample):

```
['ruby', 'uW', 'eBay', 'meditate', 'musiClean', 'medicate'].sample
```

Answer (score 4):

Create an array, and access it by index.

```
rolls = %w(ruby uW eBay meditat musiClean medicate)

puts rolls[roll_die - 1]
```